# Block merges in active Pull Request in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request, branching-and-merging

We have a dedicated process for pull requests in DevOps. The issue is that sometimes developers are merging they're changes during a review. This leads to more complex code reviews since the code changes during the review.

Is there a way to block/protect a pull request (or the underlying branch) to be changed while the review is in progress?

lets say the reviewer starts reviewing and to be able to review without additional changes the reviewer sets the branch to "protected" until he finishes the review. After finishing the review the reviewer opens the branch for the developer which has then to fix the suggested things in the code.

is there a way?

Comment: That sounds like a broken workflow. Why would you want to prevent the developer from fixing issues or improving on the PR early? DevOps gives you pull request **updates** for that exact reason. So you can just review updates and when the developer pushes new changes, you can look at the new updates to see what has changed since the last time you looked.

Comment: The issue is that while one is reviewing complex code and a developer changes this code the review gets more time consuming and tedious because these changes need to be reviewed again. basically the reviewer will be disturbed while he review the code

Comment: Then educate your developers to use drafts while they work on code, or tell them not to update their PRs too often/too quickly. If you are having trouble reviewing code, it may also mean that the PRs are simply too big.

Comment: Hi Kevin. yes I've accepted your answer and I will check if it could be a solution for us, thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to block/protect a pull request (or the underlying branch) to be changed while the review is in progress?

As far as I know, you could try to use the `Lock` feature in **Repos -> Branches**.

[image]

If the branch is locked, other users couldn't commit changes to the locked branch and complete a pull request for the locked branch.

[image]

Note：Only user who has locked the branch can commit changes and complete pull request.

After finishing the code review, the reviewer could unlock the branch. Then other users could change the branch content.

Here is a doc about [the git branch lock feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/lock-branches?view=azure-devops).